# Generating JKS file from CRT and P7b

Tags: ssl, tomcat, jks

I know how to generate a .jks file from .crt & .key file . But the ssl that I have received contains three file (.crt,.p7b ,ca bundle file). How would I generate .jks file from these file for tomcat. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like this:

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificate.p7b -out certificate.cer
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.cer -inkey privateKey.key -out certificate.pfx -certfile CACert.cer
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore certificate.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```